# Page.RegisterAsyncTask and dependent code?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, webforms, async-await

We are starting to use `Page.RegisterAsyncTask()` in our ASP.NET webforms project to add some async goodness to our site. We utilize `Page_Load` event in most of our pages and in our master page (which is in another dll). The problem we are having is the master page uses a session variable that the inherited form populates:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    If Session("Id") Is Nothing Then
        RegisterAsyncTask(New PageAsyncTask(New Func(Of Task)(Async Function()
                       Await InitializeSessionVariablesAsync(EntryPointCode.AccountAccess)
                                            End Function)))

    End If
```

In sync mode this code works fine of course because `Page_Load` for the master page gets called after `Page_Load` for the inheriting page. When using the code above you end up with errors in the master page when you try to use the session variable because the async task hasn't run yet. I wish there was a way to await the async tasks you registered.

I tried adding  `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` right after registering the call to `RegisterAsyncTask` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebForms' support for `async` is a bit awkward. In particular, [tasks registered with `RegisterAsyncTask` will be executed after `PreRender`](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45), which is [too late for `Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

One option may be to change the master code `Load` handler to a `PreRenderComplete` handler, which (if I understand correctly) should be raised after the async tasks complete.

Otherwise, you *might* be able to save the task itself in the session, something like:

```
If Session("Id") Is Nothing Then
    Session("LoadTask") = InitializeSessionVariablesAsync(EntryPointCode.AccountAccess)
End If
```

then in your master page:

```
Await Session("LoadTask")
```

But this would only work if you're using the in-proc session provider; any other provider would require serialization and would break.

So, you may need to just keep this code synchronous for now. ASP.NET MVC has similar issues today (not supporting async filters).

Comment: Guess one cant `await` in master page?

Comment: @YK1: I haven't tried it, but I see no reason why a master page couldn't use `RegisterAsyncTask` (or an `async void` handler).

Comment: @YK1: In 2021 with .NET Framework 4.8, master pages can use `RegisterAsyncTask()`. One caveat is that all .ASPX child pages that use the master page will need to have `Async="True"` in their `@Page` directives. (This was probably true 5 years ago when this question was originally asked.)

Comment: @Theophilus - how do you do this? `RegisterAsyncTask` belongs to System.Web.UI.Page, but master pages inherit from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`.

Comment: @Rocklan, I don't recall having to do anything to get `RegisterAsyncTask` to work in the master page. I did have to add `Imports System.Threading.Tasks` in master's code-behind to get the parameters of `RegisterAsyncTask` to work (like `Page.RegisterAsyncTask(New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf MyMasterPageFunctionAsync))`).